# How to remove last character string in java

Tags: java, string

I want to remove comma in last data.

example:

i have code:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i<allLines.size(); i++){
     StringBuilder temp2 = new StringBuilder();

     String[] abc = line.split("\t");

     temp2.append("{");
     temp2.append("id: \""+abc[0]+"\",");
     temp2.append("name: \""+abc[1]+"\",");
     temp2.append("},");

     temp.append(temp2.toString()); 

}

System.out.println("result : "+temp.toString());
```

ihave code and result:

```
{id: "1", name: "Jhames"},{id: "2", name: "Richard"},
```

but i want result:

```
{id: "1", name: "Jhames"},{id: "2", name: "Richard"}
```

Comment: Why are you creating another stringbuilder and appending it to your first stringbuilder?

Comment: as I said in my answer below, you just have to add 1 line to your code to get this to work temp.setLength(sb.length() - 1); but I agree you should just use the one StringBuilder as mentioned by khelwood

Comment: sorry had a typo in my original code should have been temp.setLength(temp.length() - 1);

Comment: Don't ever use `stringBuilder.append("foo" + x)` since because of concatenation this code is same as `stringBuilder.append(new StringBuilder("foo).append(x).toString())`, so as you see it kind of negates purpose of having `stringBuilder`. Instead use `stringBuilder.append("foo").append(x)`.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the new java 8 [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)! (And other nifty Java methods)

Example:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
joiner.add("foo");
joiner.add("bar");
joiner.add("baz");
String joined = joiner.toString(); // "foo,bar,baz"
```

It also supports streams in the form of `Collectors.joining(",")`

### Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "1\tJames\n2\tRichard";
    String output =  Arrays.stream(input.split("\n"))
                        .map( i -> String.format("{ id: \"%s\", name: \"%s\" }", i.split("\t")))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    //prints: { id: "1", name: "James" },{ id: "2", name: "Richard" }       
    System.out.println(output);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid appending it in the first place :

```
for (int i=0; i<allLines.size(); i++){
     StringBuilder temp2 = new StringBuilder();

     String[] abc = line.split("\t");

     temp2.append("{");
     temp2.append("id: \""+abc[0]+"\",");
     temp2.append("name: \""+abc[1]+"\",");
     temp2.append("}");
     if (i<allLines.size()-1)
         temp2.append(",");
     temp.append(temp2.toString()); 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively add this after your for loop

```
    temp.setLength(temp.length() - 1);
```

which requires no constant index checking in your code

Answer (score 2):

You can use deleteCharAt() method.

```
 StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("{id: \"1\", name: \"Jhames\"},{id: \"2\", name: \"Richard\"},");
 System.out.println(s.deleteCharAt(s.lastIndexOf(",")));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need two StringBuilders, so instead of

```
StringBuilder sb1 = ..
for(..){
    StringBuilder sb2 = ...
    //fill sb2
    sb1.append(sb2);
}
```

you should use

```
StringBuilder sb1 = ..
for(..){
    //add all you want to sb1
    sb1.append(..)
    sb1.append(..)
}
```

Next thing is that you don't ever want to do

```
sb.appent("foo" + x + "bar");
```

because it is same as

```
sb.append(new StringBuilder("foo").append(x).append("bar").toString())
```

which is very ineffective because:

1. you are creating separate StringBuilder each time you do so
2. this new StringBuilder needs to unnecessary call `toString` method which has to copy all characters to new String which will later be copied to builder, instead of calling `append(StringBuilder)` and copy its characters directly.

So instead of `sb.appent("foo" + x + "bar");` always write

```
sb.appent("foo").append(x).append("bar");
```

---

Now lets go back to your main problem. Since your code doesn't have declaration of `line` variable I am assuming that by

```
String[] abc = line.split("\t");
```

you mean

```
String[] abc = allLines.get(i).split("\t");
```

So your code can look like

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < allLines.size(); i++) {

    String[] abc = allLines.get(i).split("\t");

    temp.append("{id: \"").append(abc[0]).append("\", ");
    temp.append("name: \"").append(abc[1]).append("\"}");
    if (i < allLines.size() - 1)
        temp.append(", ");
}

System.out.println("result : " + temp.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

No Java 8 solution:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
adder(temp, allLines.get(0));

for (int i=1; i<allLines.size(); i++){
     temp.append(",");
     adder(temp, allLines.get(i));
}
System.out.println("result : "+temp.toString());

private static void adder(StringBuilder temp,String line){
    String[] abc = line.split("\t");
    temp.append("{id: \"");
    temp.append(abc[0]);
    temp.append("\",");
    temp.append("name: \"");
    temp.append(abc[1]);
    temp.append("\"}");
}
```

Comment: Please use `append` properly (don't do String concatenation inside)